# Toolbar Icon Size in PHPStorm and Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I use both these IDE's and my only annoyance is the size of the toolbar icons - they're too small for me.  Is there any way to increase the size?  I've poked around, and I haven't found a way to assign an icon larger than about 20x20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to do it.

Note that many developers prefer to disable the toolbar completely to save the vertical screen space. It doesn't provide a lot of useful features and everything that it offers can be accessed via keyboard shortcuts.

Don't know the shortcut? Not a problem at all, use `Help` | `Find Action` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: Now I just need to remember the Ctrl-Shift-A.   Thanks my crazy friend  :)

Answer (score 21):

The simplest way to fix this is to go into Settings --> Appearance & Behavior Appearance.

Then check the box "Override default fonts by (not recommended): 
Name: <"set your font"> Size: <"set your size">

This will increase the font sizes and icon toolbar sizes. This works well for HiDPI displays.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works great! In IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1, this is under Appearance> Use custom font -> Size.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this plugin. It has an option "Bigger Icons"
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10044-atom-material-icons

[image]

Comment: You are a Herro!

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, the icons are undersized. I fixed this by installing the [JB JRE here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879).

Answer (score 0):

You can use icon 23x23px. This is max size.

Answer (score 0):

Settings --> Appearance & Behavior Appearance. and again Appearance.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG8y3.png) it is shown where to look.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35738231/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*